# Surface tablet logical resolution

Tags: c#, .net, dpi

I am working on a project that requires me to get the resolution of the screen of the primary screen. I am using C# .NET 3.5 framework in Windows. For all laptops I am able to get the resolution using these two calls:

```
string width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString();
string height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height.ToString();
```

However, this does not work for Surface tablets at all as the calls return a much lower resolution than what is being displayed in the display settings of the tablets. I understand that this has to do with Windows doing special thing related to DPI and scaling the screen accordingly.

However, I am not sure how to programatically retrieve the resolution of the Surface tablets accurately (what ever the display settings are reporting those metrics).

Comment: Keep in mind that scaling is not specific to Surface tablets. High res laptops such as the Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro (and many others) scale content by default as well, so this is something your app needs to handle.

Comment: How would I go about handling it programatically? Is there an API that I can call and get the corresponding scaling values?

Comment: It depends on the technology you're using. You might find some useful info in this talk https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-535

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out the problem. I had to add to do the following in `app.manifest` file:

```
<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```